# How to delete all files > 1 Mb from the history (but keep them in the repository)

Tags: git, github, git-commit, git-filter-branch, git-rewrite-history

I have a repository with many big files (psd, exe, pdf, etc.) and every time I commit an update of those files, the git .pack file grow drastically to keep the history. How can I delete all files > 1mb from the history but keep them in the repository.

Also is it possible to setup for a particular file to never be stored in the history?

Comment: The history _is_ the repository. The files you can see are not the repository.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Using git-filter-repo

[git filter-repo](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo) is [recommended by the git project](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch#_warning) over `git filter-branch`.

```sh
git filter-repo --strip-blobs-bigger-than 1M
```

### Using BFG Repo-Cleaner

The older [BFG Repo-Cleaner](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/) used to be the most popular tool to do exactly that.

To remove all files with a size > 1 MB:

```
$ bfg --strip-blobs-bigger-than 1M  my-repo.git
```

By default it will not touch your current files.

### Don't use git filter-branch

> git filter-branch has a plethora of pitfalls that can produce non-obvious manglings of the intended history rewrite (and can leave you with little time to investigate such problems since it has such abysmal performance). These safety and performance issues cannot be backward compatibly fixed and as such, its use is not recommended.
> [Source](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch#_warning)

### Second question: how to keep specific files from being stored in the history

You can add files to `.gitignore` so that they are never added in the first place, but Git cannot be configured to delete them automatically, so you would need some kind of hook that automatically executes `bfg` or `git-filter-repo`.

### Better to prevent the problem in the first place

Tools like `bfg` are meant for rare exceptions. Ideally, you should prevent large binary files from being included in the repository in the first place. Instead, there are many other ways to preserve them, for example to add them to a GitHub release or upload them to a package repository depending on your environment, such as npm, a Maven repository or [GitHub packages](https://github.com/features/packages).

Comment: thanks but I would like to avoid any third party tools, and use instead git-filter-branch (if possible)

Comment: @zeus: Why the downvote? You can do that with git-filter-branch as well, it just won't be as fast and more complicated but as you prefer.

Comment: The downvote was not from me :( your answer is good I just want to use git official tool if possible

Comment: @zeus: I tried to find out how to do it with git filter branch but it seems as if there is no easy solution (I mean you could theoretically but at that point you have a smaller and worse version of existing tools) and it is officially discouraged, added notes and alternative git-filter-repo.