Git Blob_id with no path, how to erase it
I am not an expert with GitLab, so I am seeking help.
I have a git repository and I made the mistake to install a code inside with files bigger than 100 Mo, and I committed several times before pushing to Gitlab. Of course, when I pushed, it was not working because of files bigger than 100Mo. I succeeded in reverting the files from the commits and erasing one of the blobs, but now I have the same error with a blob_ID linked with no path.
Énumération des objets: 615, fait.
Décompte des objets: 100% (615/615), fait.
Compression par delta en utilisant jusqu'à 20 fils d'exécution
Compression des objets: 100% (299/299), fait.
Écriture des objets: 100% (578/578), 216.74 Mio | 4.47 Mio/s, fait.
Total 578 (delta 258), réutilisés 562 (delta 245), réutilisés du pack 0
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (258/258), completed with 27 local objects.
remote: GitLab: You are attempting to check in one or more blobs which exceed the 100.0MiB limit:
remote: 
remote: - 394310bc7d1d2eb1f930038862f56d80aa532aaa (110 MiB)
remote: To resolve this error, you must either reduce the size of the above blobs, or utilize LFS.
remote: You may use "git ls-tree -r HEAD | grep $BLOB_ID" to see the file path.
remote: Please refer to https://gitlab.com/help/user/free_push_limit and
remote: https://gitlab.com/help/administration/settings/account_and_limit_settings
remote: for further information.


and when I am doing :
git ls-tree -r HEAD | grep 394310bc7d1d2eb1f930038862f56d80aa532aaa

nothing happened
I don't know how to remove this blob from all my previous commits.
Thank you for your help.

Might squash commits in a branch, so the squashed commit would not have that huge file, as here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25356855/1075282

I am not sure to understand, but if I am doing that, it will squashed the commits even if I want to keep the commits (because I did other modifications that I want to keep) ?

Yes, if commits are to be kept, squashing all is not an option.

This git ls-tree command shows only contents of the given commit, HEAD. But, as you said, it does not contain the file anymore. Look at earlier commits for the blob: HEAD~1, HEAD~2, you get the idea.

git ls-tree -r HEAD will only list blobs in the active commit (the HEAD commit).
If you want to look for commits in the history of your current branch that contain that blob, you may try:
git log --name-status --find-object=<blob_id>

Add --branches if you want to look in the history of all branches.

Thank you, so I found out it was from other files in a folder (let's called it FOLDER_BF) that I put in the recent commits in a .gitignore . I tried to supress these files by doing :
git filter-branch --index-filter 'rm -f FOLDER_BF' -- --all
But when I am pushing, I still have the same problem :/

@arkhose: you are probably looking for this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72123719/86072

watch out: if you are removing files from your history, the consequence is you may well be: you have deleted these files without a restore option. Obviously: I assume you have a backup of all files that could be relevant to you.

This solution is working in my case thank you for helping. And yes I made a backup before that ;)
